VS2022 updates broke resource file?
Try to add new resource file, get this error immediately after adding

Try to add a new item into existing file, no error, but it doesn't run the custom tool

The properties of the resource file, which had been working all the while until yesterday's update

When I try to use the entry in my page, the newly added entry doesn't exist.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.11.0
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.11.0+35208.52
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032
Installed Version: Community
ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.11.230.51983
ASP.NET and Web Tools
C# Tools   4.11.0-3.24374.1+f99bb16a395e48a05520ba7af1549b20bfdeee36
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.11.3.2436904+f07c7bb8e623ebcc1e1028cf11d101f866c77a79
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.
Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

Answering my own question.
Temporary work around.

Create another entry in the resource file
Save the file
Reopen the file
Select the temporary entry (make sure you select the entire row using the far left column). And delete it.

Some how it works for me.
Don't ask me way.

This is caused by some missing support assemblies in your installation.If more detail such as logs(at
%APPDATA%\Local\Temp\VsProjectFault_xxx.failure.txt
)can be shared it maybe helpful for others to take a deeper look but reinstalling VS with all necessary workload could fix this.

@AmadeuszLiu I did a search C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp>dir /s/a/b *fault*, but can't find any filename with fault. Guess it is something else.

That's weird.Maybe the only approach is reverting the upgrade.VS should generate a logfile for these types of errors.

I am developing the Resource Explorer there. Stumbled upon this question from here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Resource-file-cant-access-byte/10727183
I suspect the issue was that the Resource Explorer was adding your file as a System.String instead of a System.Byte[]. We have changed that, differentiating between a text file (System.String) and a file (System.Byte[]).
If you want to give it a try, the fix should be soon in the VS preview version (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/#download-preview).
As for the old experience, it is still available through: Solution Explorer > right click the resource file > Open With... > Managed Resource Editor (Legacy). Hope this unblocks you!
If you have any other feedback on that experience, please consider opening feedback tickets at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio, mentioning "Resource Explorer" should come my way :) thanks!

I add a file in resources with type: file, but when the process is complete, in resources a file with type: string appears. Is this a bug?  I used Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.11.4

Old version, when I a add file to resources the output is byte[], but today it changed to string? Its bug?

Thanks. I was not able to upload xlsx files today, but the legacy editor worked. Drag and drop is much easier than the new UI, hopefully it will be available for a long time. Especially considering the new one doesn't work.

New resource explorer just now simply stopped generating the code for a newly added string (single word, name and value equal). Old resource editor works as normal and generates the entry without issues.
When need to type a lot of name value pairs, the old editor is much easier, as you no need to click->add every time. Please consider ease of use before changing things

I also had problems with the resource file after updating to VS2022 ver 7.11.0
In my case, WPF desktop App, .Net 6.
I have a file Byte[] previously imported to the resource, that I later write out to disk using "WriteAllBytes()". If I use the original Byte[] file previously imported before update, all works fine. But if I replace the file using the new resource interface, the WriteAllBytes() function fails with the following:

System.MissingMethodException: 'Constructor on type 'System.Byte[]'
not found.'

Similar problem occurs if I use WriteAllText() on a newly imported string file, (but works on previously imported strings file)
My solution was to rollback the update until a workaround or help on solving this can be found. RollBack can be done via the VS Installer.

The new resource editor is indeed a proverbial pain in the backside. Even after a few more updates (currently on 7.11.5) its still buggy as f***.
Currently for me its even causing my entire Visual Studio to crash, loosing code in the proces.
For now my workaround is to open them trough right click -> open with and select Managed Resource Editor (Legacy). Just select this option and press the Default button to revert back to the classic editor as a default till Microsoft can wrap its head around and fix it.
Perhaps Microsoft can also learn to release features like this after a more extensive testing phase as should be done with all software development?

Thanks for this (sad but) working solution!
